# Why Odoo removes milliseconds in Datetime fields?

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have a method in which `self` is a simple `stock.move` record. Besides, as you may know, `stock.move` model has a `Datetime` field named `date`. If I write this code inside the method:

```
lines = self.search([
    ('date', '=', self.date),
])
```

It should return me at least the current line. And it does, but only in some servers. Others return nothing. Why? Because if I do a query to get the `date` in PostgreSQL, the servers which are working OK return *2017-12-27 17:10:00*, however, the servers which are working wrong return *2017-12-27 17:10:00.131112*. So, for the cases with miliseconds the ORM `search` method is doing this:

```
lines = self.search([
    (2017-12-27 17:10:00.131112, '=', 2017-12-27 17:10:00),
])
```

`self.date` is returning the `Datetime` value without the miliseconds and that's why the comparison fails. I need to get the miliseconds too.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Actually I think that `create_date` and `write_date` fields should have miliseconds. `Datetime` fields shouldn't have because the `DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT` constant is used. So I don't know what's happening in your case

Answer (score 1):

Absolute right, I confirm here odoo Datetime does not keep timestame in UTC, it store datetime in UTC. Even since odoo 5.0 we working on it, till date.

In Odoo 11.0

```
 id  |        create_date         |         write_date         |    date_expected    
-----+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------------------
  41 | 2017-12-21 13:06:06.927814 | 2017-12-21 13:06:06.927814 | 2017-12-21 13:01:30
   7 | 2017-12-21 08:33:22.431197 | 2017-12-21 08:33:22.431197 | 2017-12-21 08:31:54
  42 | 2017-12-21 13:07:03.659194 | 2017-12-21 13:07:03.659194 | 2017-12-21 13:06:54
   2 | 2017-12-21 07:24:24.953689 | 2017-12-21 07:24:24.953689 | 2017-12-21 07:24:25
```

Yes. odoo create_date, write_date able to gives you millisecond, might it helpful you. but sure in Datetime, not allow to do so...

In case you need really millisecond based needs, Additional field add to store millisecond, than all it works.

Problem persist in odoo `Community` and `Enterprise` edition both.

*** NEED ADDITIONAL SMALL CUSTOMIZATION

Comment: If I add an additional field to get the miliseconds, from where do I have to take its value? Users fill in field `date`, and in ORM `create` method I get the datetime with no miliseconds, so I can't tell `create` to store the milisecond part into the additional field. However, I solved my particular problem adding +1 second in the search comparison, but my solution doesn't answer the question I'm doing.

Comment: Overide odoo create method, in that you can store timestamp or millisecond in additional field, directly. I am not sure what you working on module, but create method helps to resovle this.

Comment: I just computed a char field to store write_date formatted with  milliseconds
read_date_time = rec.create_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')